# What browsers support CSS #parent > .direct-child notation? (no jQuery)

Tags: css, browser-support

As far as I know, the > (`#test>div`) means that the `div` is required to be a direct child of `#test`.

Where a space (`#test div`) means that it can be a descendant/ancestor relationship. So `#test p div` would be affected by simply a reference to `#test div`

What browsers support the first one mentioned?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can find information for all selectors at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html
For your questions the supported browsers are the following:

IE 7, IE8, IE9 pr3, FF 3.0, FF 3.5, FF 3.6, FF 4b1, Saf 4.0 Win, Saf 5.0 Win, Chrome 4, Chrome 5, Opera 10.10,  Opera 10.53 and Opera 10.60

**Edit:** Since it's 2015 I would suggest to have as reference for such questions the [can I use?](http://caniuse.com/) website. For example you can find more info for [child selector](http://caniuse.com/#search=child%20selector).

Answer (score 2):

FF2+, IE7+, Opera/Safari/Chrome ( any modern version of the latter ) should support the child selector.

Answer (score 0):

It works great on IE7 (at least) unless you use #div > *, as I've just found out.